# Is there a limit on how many values an Entity in Wit.Ai can have?

Tags: wit.ai

I created a Wit.AI entity with about 10k values. When I input a message that is exactly one of the the possible values, Wit.AI doesn't seem to be able to pick that up. I tried this with an entity that has only a few values and it worked. Is this because of the amount of values that the entity has?

Comment: Could you post the code that you have?

Comment: I am just using the API to try to get the meaning from sentences. https://api.wit.ai/message

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your Wit app has stories, the stories may be taking precedence over any other training data you have provided (e.g. entities and their values), because [Wit intentionally overfits on stories](https://wit.ai/blog/2016/04/12/bot-engine).

Make sure you delete any stories if you want your AI to be sensitive to a large training dataset.